# Picking components for a battery power pack

Tags: batteries, stm32, battery-charging, texas-instruments

I am a first-year Computer Engineering student building my first PCB and decided to go ahead and build a battery pack similar to the [Shargeek Storm 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09NY8GN76). I am using an STM32F103C8T6, an SPI-controlled small OLED screen, a TPS25850 for Two USB C power outputs, an SGM452 temperature sensor for the batteries, and a BQ24610 for Battery management and charging from a USB C input. I am aiming for ideally a 15W output for both USBC output devices and I want to see if anyone has any critiques for the components I am using or if they know of better components that I can use in this battery pack. Also, all of my USBC inputs/outputs are operating at 5V.

Comment: You are basically asking what components you should buy, right? The problem is, that's off-topic.